# simulators not showing on xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcode6

So I was making an app on xcode and usually next to the run and stop button in the top left corner it shows the different simulators and my ios device, but for some reason it isnt there? Is there a way to show it or did it get removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try the (command + B) action to build and run your project.

I will try to play around the settings to see if you can make the buttons reappear.

Comment: In the view tab, there is an option to hide / show toolbar. Try to toggle this.